# Windows UWP and how ADD About Page

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, uwp-xaml

How can I add this menu to the top navigation for select about page and privacy policy pages into my application ? And fullscreen mode icon and logic ?

[image]
[image]

I search on google, but without any help results

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These buttons are shown only with older Windows 8.x apps as kind of backwards compatibility, however you can add your own buttons to the title bar.. Take a look [here](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952) and [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/10/20/how-to-place-custom-xaml-content-in-the-windows-universal-apps-title-bar/).